# How to preserve images metadata after Google Drive sync?

Tags: google-drive-api, metadata

I need to preserve metadata (meta comments, meta tags) on images after they sync with Gogle Drive.

Scneario:

1. I add an image to a folder using a Mac.
2. I add meta comments.
3. Google Drive syncs the image
4. I access the image in my (Windows Server) Virtual Machine

The meta comments are gone. Is there a way to preserve that data?

Thanks

Comment: Check the documentation about the [Custom File Properties](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/properties), `Properties are accessed using the 'properties' (visible to all apps) and 'appProperties' (restricted to single apps) fields on`[**`files`**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files). `Using properties will allow your app to store additional metadata on a file, such as tags, IDs from other data stores, viewing preferences etc. Properties can be used to share metadata between applications, for example, in a workflow application.`